# use python ssh run local shell script to remote

Tags: python, ssh, paramiko

I am sorry for my bad english.
I search solution  for my question some day,but not found.

this is my question:
i have some manager shell script in server-A.
i use

```
ssh username@other_server_ip < shell_script.sh
```

is run OK.

i want to do this in python.
i was test this:

```
1\paramiko, 'exec_command (str)' is only run ONE command.and i use stdin to invoke_shell,not ok
2\pexect,sendline() is only ONE command.
```

**Please help me,thanks!**

(some AIX not support sft,so i not want use sftp script to other server. )

the shell script like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
if [ $# -lt 1 ]
os=`uname`
if [ "$os" = "linux" ] || [ "$os" = "Linux" ]
then
  temp=`df -P $diskname| tail -1`
  if [ "$temp" = "" ]
  then
    echo "error!t=$diskname not found"
    exit 0
  fi
  # diskutil=`echo $temp|awk '{printf("%s",$5)}'|awk '{gsub("%",""); print $0}'`
  disk_size=`echo $temp | awk '{print $2}'`
  disk_size_mb=`expr $disk_size / 1024`
  disk_size=`echo | awk '{ printf("%.2f",(c1/1024.0)) }' c1=$disk_size_mb`
  disk_size="${disk_size}"

elif [ "$os" = "SunOS" ]
then
  temp=`df -k $diskname | tail -1`
  ....

elif [ "$os" = "AIX" ] || [ "$os" = "aix" ]
then
  temp=`df -k $diskname |tail -1|sed -e "s/%//g"`
  ....
else 
  echo "error!!=Unsupported platform: $os"
  exit
fi

echo "Total Size=$disk_size_mb"
```

Answer (score 0):

If just triggering the script from Python is enough, use `subprocess.call` from the standard library. From looking at your script, I guess it's being run on a number of remote hosts, probably in parallel. You might want to have a look at the excellent [fabric](http://fabfile.org) module. It's a wrapper around `paramiko` which greatly facillitates running commands both locally and remotely and transfering files up and down.